# Google Sheets: Combine All Hyperlinked URL per Company

Tags: google-sheets

There are 2 columns in Google Sheets. Column A contains "Company Name" (eg: Apple, Microsoft). Column B contains "Product URL" (eg: [iPhone](https://iPhone.com), [Macbook](https://www.apple.com/mac/), [Xbox](https://www.xbox.com), [Office](https://www.Office.com)).

My objective is to combine all the hyperlinked URL into one cell per company. Therefore Column A would have a unique company's name. And Column B would have a list of all matching products (including hyperlink) per that company.

Unfortunately the formula below will not hyperlink the products.

```
=LET(A, A3:A, ux, UNIQUE(A),idx, FILTER(XMATCH(ux, A), COUNTIF(A, ux)>0), MAP(SEQUENCE(ROWS(A)), LAMBDA(s, IF(ISNA(XMATCH(s, idx)), "", TEXTJOIN(char(10)&char(10),, FILTER(B3:B, A=INDEX(A,s)))))))
```

[Google Sheets Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zC1ZHR4042ldJ3cxXzJunxYRvZV6wiPq2ZT5pKg65Dc/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Are you open to using an Apps Script option via a custom script? It seems quite impossible to achieve this solely using the preloaded Google Apps Script functions.

Comment: @SputnikDrunk2, Yes I am open to using Google App Script for custom script. I figured it's impossible using preloaded functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## ALTERNATIVE SUGGESTION

As mentioned, it appears that your goal may not be achievable solely through the use of built-in Google Sheets functions. As suggested, you could consider trying the *custom Apps Script* sample provided below, which adds a Google Sheets custom menu named ***Copy Hyperlinks***. For more context, please refer to the sample demonstration and script provided below:

[image]

---

### *Sample Script*

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
var data = sheet.getActiveRange().getRichTextValues();
var startRow = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
var companyCol = 'D'; //Change this column letter where you want to place the 'company' name
var productURLCol = 'E' //Change this column letter where you want to place the 'Product URLs'
var spacing;

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Copy Hyperlinks')
    .addItem('Copy Links', 'run')
    .addToUi();
}

function run() {
  const column1 = [...new Set(data.map(x => x.map((y, i) => i == 0 && y.getText()).filter(z => z)).flat())];
  const rawData = data.map(x => x.map((y, i) => y.getLinkUrl() ? [y.getText(), y.getLinkUrl()] : [y.getText()]));

  column1.forEach(company => {
    const data = rawData.filter(x => x[0] == company);
    const companyName = [...new Set(data.map(x => x[0]).flat())];
    const productNames = data.map(x => x[1][0]);
    const productURLs = data.map(x => x[1][1])
    spacing = data.length;

    //Collate and generate URL for each data
    generateLinks(companyName, productNames, productURLs);

    startRow = startRow + spacing;

  });
}

function generateLinks(company, productNames, productURLs) {
  const column1Value = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
    .setText(company)
    .build();

  const column2valueBuilder = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
    .setText(productNames.join(`\n\n`));

  productNames.forEach((x, i) => {
    //Process URLs here
    column2valueBuilder.setLinkUrl(productNames.join('\n\n').indexOf(x), (productNames.join('\n\n').indexOf(x) + x.length), productURLs[i]);
  });

  const column2value = column2valueBuilder.build();

  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange(`${companyCol}${startRow}`).setRichTextValue(column1Value);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange(`${productURLCol}${startRow}`).setRichTextValue(column2value);
}
```

---

### Steps to test this sample script:

1. [Add a container bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#or) to your Google Sheet file.
2. Copy the sample script from here, paste and save it on your container bound script.
3. Reload your Sheet file tab to see the `Copy Hyperlinks` custom menu.
4. Or at the top of the Apps Script editor, select the `onOpen` function and click **Run** then check the `Copy Hyperlinks` custom menu on your sheet file.

### *References*

- [Container-bound Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound)
- [Class RichTextValueBuilder (setLinkUrl)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder#setLinkUrl(Integer,Integer,String))